# Source code viewable in Chrome JS console

Tags: meteor

Haven't found an answer to this anywhere, so I'll try SO...

When I run my Meteor app on localhost and navigate to me Chrome JS console and under the "Sources" tab, I can see the entire source code of my code in my lib folder.

I put most of my code in the lib folder of my meteor app because it's necessary that the code loads before anything else in order for everything in my client templates to render correctly. I've placed it in the lib folder every since I started building the app months ago.

Anyway, is the source code going to be viewable like this if the app goes into production without the insecure package? Or will I be forced to move the code over to the client and re-configure my entire script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor's source code open to the clients?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945669/meteors-source-code-open-to-the-clients)

Comment: Once your app is in production (such as after a `meteor deploy`) it is bundled and minified, which means that client browsers will only see random minified code when accessing your deployed website. Note that this does **not** constitute a security, as de-minifiers and other advances tools exist. The `insecure` package has nothing to do with this, it only allows all client operations on Collections.

Comment: @Kyll How accurate are these de-minifiers? They don't look too accurate to me from experience when trying to make the code look legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put server code you want to hide from the client under `/server`
2. Put code that needs to run on both client and server under `/lib`
3. Put client-only code under `/client`
4. Do not put *secrets* (ex: auth keys) in any code. Use environment variables or a `config.json` file.
5. The *insecure* and *autopublish* packages have nothing to do with javascript code visibility, only with collection *data*.

As @Kyll said, all your client and lib code will be minified and concatenated into one giant file and visible to all clients. js can be de-minified but that won't restore the original variable names or any comments of course. An attacker can step through your client code, save it, and generally reverse-engineer it at will. That doesn't mean it's easy.

You may find [these resources](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/11/meteor-security-no-3-useful-resources.html) helpful.

Comment: helloo @MichelFloyd ... what do you mean with `js can be de-minified but that won't restore the original variable names`..?? does it mean minified version will change variable names..?? any resource for this..?? thank You...

Comment: Meteor minification includes shortening variable names to a, b, c... etc... afaik it uses [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) which is extensively documented in terms of what it can do to your code. Look at the [minified js for atmospherejs](https://atmospherejs.com/cd2aba30d4bc1bad02b1d8d91ec8d5a7096cc02d.js) for an example. Global variables, collection names, and string literals are not affected. Trying to deduce what's going on in production in minified code is a bit of an art!

Answer (score 0):

Users will always be able to see all client side code through the console which is why anything security related should be server side only. I would just split it up into the server and client directory and server/lib and client/lib if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Insecure when present helps you in accessing the db from the client without restrictions. (console interactions).

when removed it will revoke all access that client might be having to db and the only way to do interactions with the db would be with the help of Meteor Methods and Calls.

You may also need to remove autopublish and replace the same with Meteor.Publish and Meteor Subscribe.

Please review the below links for more info
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/security-with-methods
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe

Hope this Helps